# Vue.JS "TypeError: reverseMessage is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display a string in reverse, using Vue. My template is:

```
<div id="app">
  <reverse :msgreverse="message" :reverseMessage="reverseMessage()"></reverse>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
function reverseMessage(msg) {
  return msg.split('').reverse().join('')
}

Vue.component('reverse', {
  props:["msgreverse", "reverseMessage"],
  template: '<p v-html="reverseMessage(msgreverse)"></p>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message:'The message to reverse !',
  }
})
```

This fails with the following console errors:

- TypeError: reverseMessage is not a function. (In 'reverseMessage()', 'reverseMessage' is undefined)
- Error in render: "TypeError: reverseMessage is not a function. (In 'reverseMessage()', 'reverseMessage' is undefined)"
- Property or method "reverseMessage" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

How do I get the `<reverse>` component to display a given string in reverse?

Comment: Your `reverseMessage` function has to be defined as your Vue instance method inside of `methods: {}`. Check if that works. Also, isn't it better to define it in your `reverse` component and call it there (without the prop)? It's what's that component is for after all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The errors you're seeing are due to the fact that Vue is not aware of the global function you've defined (i.e., `reverseMessage()`). Vue does not provide access to global functions/variables when rendering templates. The local functions it has access to are declared in the component's `methods` property. In your case, it would look like this:

```
Vue.component('reverse', {
  // ...
  methods: {
    reverseMessage(msg) {
      return msg.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

Since it seems that component's purpose is to reverse the given string, there's no need to specify a `prop` for the `reverseMessage` function, so you can remove it from `props`:

```
Vue.component('reverse', {
  // ...
  //props:["msgreverse", "reverseMessage"],  // DON'T DO THIS
  props:["msgreverse"],
})
```

Your template uses the `v-html` directive to show the reversed message, but that's unnecessary because (1) the message itself is not HTML, and (2) [Vue recommends against it for user input](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

Instead, you should use [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) for this:

```
Vue.component('reverse', {
  // ...
  //template: '<p v-html="reverseMessage(msgreverse)"></p>'  // DON'T DO THIS
  template: '<p>{{reverseMessageg(msgreverse)}}</p>'
})
```

```js
Vue.component('reverse', {
  props: ['msgreverse'],
  methods: {
    reverseMessage(msg) {
      return msg.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  },
  template: '<p>{{reverseMessage(msgreverse)}}</p>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <reverse :msgreverse="message"></reverse>
</div>
```